# Unable to add txt file of computers into SCCM collection

Tags: powershell, sccm

I am trying to add 400 computer to a collection and I have an error running the powershell in SCCM. I try to change the . to _ but also encounter the same error.

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Char] does not contain a method named 'Split'.
At line:8 char:5
+     $collectionname = $filenames.Name[$x].Split(".")[0]
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

**Powershell:**

```
  #Set path to collection directory
$collectiondir = "D:\Collections\"

#Pull only .TXT files into array
$filenames = Get-ChildItem $collectiondir* -include *.txt

for ($x=0; $x -lt ($filenames.Length); $x++) {
    $collectionname = $filenames.Name[$x].Split(".")[0]
    $collectionname
    #Add new collection based on the file name
    try {
        New-CMDeviceCollection -Name $collectionname -LimitingCollectionName "All Systems"
        }
    catch {
        "Error creating collection - collection may already exist: $collectionname" | Out-File "$collectiondir\$collectionname`_invalid.log" -Append
        }

    #Read list of computers from the text file
    $computers = Get-Content $filenames[$x]
    foreach($computer in $computers) {
        try {
            Add-CMDeviceCollectionDirectMembershipRule  -CollectionName $collectionname -ResourceId $(get-cmdevice -Name $computer).ResourceID
            }
        catch {
            "Invalid client or direct membership rule may already exist: $computer" | Out-File "$collectiondir\$collectionname`_invalid.log" -Append
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to have that clumsy for, change the index to just behind `$filenames[$x].Name.Split(".")[0]` But I'd prefer a simple `foreach ($filename in $filenames) {`

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same error message. If i were to use the simpler, i would get the error.                 `Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:19 char:30
+     $computers = Get-Content $filenames[$x]
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have made a mistake following my hints, both do work:

```
$collectiondir = "D:\Collections\"

#Pull only .TXT files into array
$filenames = Get-ChildItem -Path $collectiondir -Filter *.txt

for ($x=0; $x -lt ($filenames.Length); $x++) {
    $collectionname = $filenames[$x].Name.Split(".")[0]
    $collectionname
}
"-----"
ForEach ($file in $filenames){
    $collectionname = $file.Name.Split(".")[0]
    $collectionname

}
```

If you wanted to split the extension a better way is to simply use BaseName instead of Name

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how it works for you and not for me. `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:8 char:5
+     $collectionname = $filenames[$x].Name.Split(".")[0]
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull`

Comment: what is the content of $filenames and the type? Insert `$filenames|gm` in front of the for.

Comment: it's just a text file with the computer name. I also tested another text file with the full FQDN computer name.

Comment: From your (and mine) code $filenames contains an array of file objects from 'Get-ChildItem', if the list is empty the for doesn't iterate and can't have a null value. Yor are doing something different.

Comment: At which line in which version does the error occur?

Comment: At line 12. version refers to my SCCM version ?

Comment: Problem is you already assigned `$collectionname` a string value. I'm not familiar with SCCM and it's cmdlets - I think this is a new error and a new question albeit connected.